# Android how String from Api parse into int

Tags: android, google-maps, parsing, retrofit

I get the data from the api , lat and lon to Google maps, but they are String in the api , a Google map takes only int, i tried:

```
String lonOfPlace = places.getLon();
String latOfPlace = places.getLat();
int lon = Integer.parseInt(places.getLon());
int lat = Integer.parseInt(places.getLat());
Integer.valueOf(lonOfPlace);
Integer.valueOf(latOfPlace);
```

but it does not work, tell me how to do pls

There i nedd the data:

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {

    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
            .title(nameOfPlace)
            .snippet(categoryOfPlace);
```

Places class:

```
public class Places implements Serializable {


String name;
String geometry_name;
String rating;
String subcategory_name;
String favorite;
String csv_image;
String lon;
String lat;

public Places(String name, String geometry_name, String rating,String subcategory_name, String favorite,String csv_image,String lon, String lat) {
    this.name = name;
    this.geometry_name = geometry_name;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.subcategory_name = subcategory_name;
    this.favorite = favorite;
    this.csv_image = csv_image;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.lat = lat;

}
```

Api if you need: http://gdetut.com/api/firms?salt=63926e380bdc96ef990d57898daeb71c&category_id=1

Comment: I think @ρяσѕρєяK answer will work try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As see here:

[LatLng:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) Class constructor takes `double` instead of `int` so need to parse `String` to `double` instead of `int`.

```
double lon = Double.parseDouble(places.getLon());
double lat = Double.parseDouble(places.getLat());
```

Comment: I'm sorry , really , I'm a fool , thank you very much = )